# ProgressBar iOS 13

Tags: swift, swiftui, progress-bar, combine

I've tried creating my own `ProgressView` to support iOS 13, but for some reason it appears to not work. I've tried `@State`, `@Binding` and the plain `var progress: Progress`, but it doesn't update at all.

```swift
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: Progress

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("\(Int(progress.fractionCompleted))% completed")
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                    .frame(height: 4)
                GeometryReader { metrics in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width: metrics.size.width * CGFloat(progress.fractionCompleted))
                }
            }.frame(height: 4)
            Text("\(progress.completedUnitCount) of \(progress.totalUnitCount)")
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

In my content view I added both the iOS 14 variant and the iOS 13 supporting one. They look the same, but the iOS 13 variant does not change anything.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 10)
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressBar(progress: $progress)
                .padding()
                .onReceive(timer) { timer in
                    progress.completedUnitCount += 1
                    if progress.isFinished {
                        self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                        progress.totalUnitCount = 500
                    }
                }
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                ProgressView(progress)
                    .padding()
                    .onReceive(timer) { timer in
                        progress.completedUnitCount += 1
                        if progress.isFinished {
                            self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                            progress.totalUnitCount = 500
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The iOS 14 variant works, but my iOS 13 implementation fails. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Progress is-a NSObject, it is not a struct, so state does not work for it. You have to use KVO to observe changes in Progress and redirect into SwiftUI view's source of truth.

Here is a simplified demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
class ProgressBarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fractionCompleted: Double
    let progress: Progress
    private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation!
    
    init(_ progress: Progress) {
        self.progress = progress
        self.fractionCompleted = progress.fractionCompleted
        observer = progress.observe(\.completedUnitCount) { [weak self] (sender, _) in
            self?.fractionCompleted = sender.fractionCompleted
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressBar: View {
    @ObservedObject private var vm: ProgressBarViewModel
    
    init(_ progress: Progress) {
        self.vm = ProgressBarViewModel(progress)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("\(Int(vm.fractionCompleted * 100))% completed")
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                    .frame(height: 4)
                GeometryReader { metrics in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width: metrics.size.width * CGFloat(vm.fractionCompleted))
                }
            }.frame(height: 4)
            Text("\(vm.progress.completedUnitCount) of \(vm.progress.totalUnitCount)")
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

and updated call place to use same constructor

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 10)
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressBar(progress)      // << here !!

// ... other code
```